# How do i find out how long my uk ban is?

Tags: uk, ireland, visa-bans, jamaican-citizens

We lived in the UK from 2012 on ancestry visa, which we applied to be extended in 2017, but South Africa lost my children's passport, so they invalidated that application.  In the meantime my husband’s passport expired while with the UK Home Office and they refused to send it back for us to apply for his new one in London, it took 9 months for the UK Home Office to send it back.
We managed to get the children's passport and resubmitted, but because my husband’s had expired and South Africa was taking so long to return his, the UK Home Office told us we needed to leave and paid for our tickets home. The VRS sent an email saying we overstayed since 2017 and they would not take any of our appeals into account.

I'm trying to find out how long we are banned for and can I enter Ireland or should I just wait?

Comment: The Republic of Ireland or Northern Ireland?

Answer (score 1):

Your UK entry ban is either 2 or 5 years, depending on whether the date of your departure was less or more than 6 months after the date on which you were either:
• given notice of their removal decision
• no longer had a pending appeal against that decision (appeal rights exhausted)
https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/606970/GI-Re-entry-bans-v7.pdf#page5

If you don’t have the paperwork, you can make a Subject Access Request https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration

Jamaican nationals need a visa to enter the Republic of Ireland. http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa The UK and the Republic of Ireland are part of the Common Travel Area; they share Immigration data which makes it highly unlikely you’d get one.